# does signing EXE solve security warning

Tags: c++, windows, email, certificate, self-signed

I wrote a simple c++ console app (it is just a hello world app), but when I send it over email, I get an error "These files cannot be opened".

I also self signed the app, but I get the same error.

The endgame is a simple app that will be sent to my client, and I cannot have this warning. Will purchasing a certificate and signing the code solve this issue? I really do not want to pay money for a certificate I do not need.

Comment: This sounds like a matter of email security. Either you or your client have their email client set to block `.exe` attachments, which is pretty common nowadays. Signing will probably not help. You can try emailing `notepad.exe` which is certainly signed, but I guess the same error will occur.

Answer (score 1):

When I need to send an .exe through email ,I change its extension to an unknown one , and it is sent as a normal file.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you wanna send a .zip file that contains the .exe, so you can also add any other required files or READMEs.